# magento shopping cart price rule does not let me add a condition

Tags: javascript, magento

I am trying to create a discount code to apply to items only in a specific category. In the past I have gone to conditions and clicked the plus + button to add, but today when I click it, nothing comes up. At the bottom of the screen it says javascript:void(0), I have tried on different computers and browsers and it's always the same. I also tried updating java but it did not make a difference. Please help?!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to get familiar with basic rules of the service. Your question sounds as off-topic one. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you can find some information about how to ask a good question.

Comment: I would recommend adding more info about about what causes the problem.  Does not look like there is enough info here for someone to help.